# Change Prefix of Logcat output

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-logcat

salam
how to change prefix of Logcat for removing all prefix like date and time , ...

```
Log.i("H", "Hi");
```

output :

```
06-02 08:58:22.060: INFO/H(1716): Hi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  But since logcat is just a unix program, you can pipe it into cut or sed to alter your view of it.  I don't think I'd ever do that though-  the timing data can help solve lots of bugs, and can help you find things like core dumps in the logs.